# Import Error with mod_wsgi httpd and a Flask Application

Tags: python, apache, flask, jinja2, mod-wsgi

Okay so here is the error I am receiving when someone attempts to access the server. (from the error_log)

## Error

```
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15] mod_wsgi (pid=19122): Target WSGI script '/var/www/QuickSearch/quicksearch.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15] mod_wsgi (pid=19122): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/QuickSearch/quicksearch.wsgi'.
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]   File "/var/www/QuickSearch/quicksearch.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]     from quicksearch import app
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]   File "/var/www/QuickSearch/QuickSearch/quicksearch.py", line 5, in <module>
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]     from flask import Flask
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15]     from jinja2 import Markup, escape
[Wed Dec 14 11:49:12 2016] [error] [client 10.0.2.15] ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

## My Directory

quicksearch.py is the main application, the rest is html ect for the website

```
/var/www/QuickSearch/
|-- QuickSearch
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- quicksearch.py
|   |-- static
|   |   |-- css
|   |   |-- fonts
|   |   `-- js
|   `-- templates
`-- quicksearch.wsgi
```

## quicksearch.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/prod/mts/platform/sandboxes/rhel6/mts-build-09/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

activate_this = '/var/www/QuickSearch/QuickSearch/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/QuickSearch/QuickSearch/")
sys.path.append("/var/www/QuickSearch/")

from quicksearch import app as application
```

## quicksearch.conf

This is the config file for the server

```
WSGIPythonPath "/var/www/QuickSearch/QuickSearch/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.2.15

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/QuickSearch/quicksearch.wsgi
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    <Directory /var/www/QuickSearch/QuickSearch/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am at a complete loss, I've been trying to solve this for two days and have no idea what to do next. I have looked at similar threads to this and still haven't found a solution. If you need any information to help solve this please post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6. You cannot force it to use a Python virtual environment using Python 2.7. This is explained in mod_wsgi documentation on Python virtual environments at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

You will need to install a mod_wsgi version which is compiled for Python 2.7.